# Interface callback after startactivity

Tags: android, interface, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have fragment that contains recyclerview and products inside of it. When click row opens a new activity (SuggestionActivity). This activity also contains recyclerview inside of suggested products. When I click this  products selecting or deselecting. Under the recyclerview I have button and when clicked this button it should be listen first recyclerview adapter and notifying data.

Ex: 
ProductsFragment -> RecyclerAdapter -> Click Row -> Open Activity -> Click one or multiple rows and select -> Click Button -> Close activity and notify fragment adapter

---

My first recyclerview inside fragment

> ```
> public class MyView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
>
>         public MyView(View view) {
>             super(view);
>
>             view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onClick(View view) {
>
>                     SuggestionActivity x = new SuggestionActivity();
>                     x.setTab2AdapterListener(new SuggestionActivity.Tab2AdapterListener() {
>                         @Override
>                         public void interfaceClicked() {
>                             Log.d("interfaceClicked", "interfaceClicked"); // This line doesn't work!
>                         }
>                     });
>
>
>                     Intent i = new Intent(mContext, SuggestionActivity.class);
>                     i.putExtra("first", String.valueOf(tag));
>                     i.putExtra("second", String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()));
>                     mContext.startActivity(i);
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>     }
> ```

My Interface defined on SuggestionActivity

> ```
> private Tab2AdapterListener tab2AdapterListener;
> public interface Tab2AdapterListener {
>     void interfaceClicked();
> }
> public void setTab2AdapterListener(Tab2AdapterListener tab2AdapterListener) {
>     this.tab2AdapterListener = tab2AdapterListener;
> }
> ```

And Button inside SuggestionActivity

> ```
> btnSendSuggestions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View view) {
>                 String suggested = "";
>                 for (int i = 0; i < suggestedProductsList.size(); i++) {
>                     if (suggestedProductsList.get(i).getIsSelected())
>                         suggested += suggestedProductsList.get(i).getProductId() + ",";
>                 }
>                 if ( suggested.length() > 0 ) {
>                     suggested = suggested.substring(0, suggested.length() - 1);
>                 }
>
>                 if (tab2AdapterListener != null)
>                     tab2AdapterListener.interfaceClicked();
>                  // tab2AdapterListener comes null
>             }
>         });
> ```

Comment: use `Handler` to pass message in fragment.

Comment: I did solve my problem but not using with callback. I did use singleton for my data changing and fragment onResume func run when activity finish. And I force the adapter.notifydatachanged() and it worked!

Comment: it's not a good Idea bro.

Comment: yeah i know, I want only notify my array model so onresume method on fragment not a bad idea i think, if you show a example with using handler I can try it. Thank you for answers.